# Is possible avoid internal number conversion on isNaN() function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

As the title of the question says, I want to avoid the internal number conversion on the isNaN() function.

isNaN() function try to convert the input parameter to a number calling to the Number() function.

For example, if a user puts a value `false` in an input text who is tested with the isNaN() function to see if the input data is "not a number", the result will be "false", because the Number() function performs a conversion of the value false to 0.

So, it's possible do this? For example, using a pragma or something?

Thanks!

Comment: `Number("false")` is `NaN` and `isNaN("false")` is true. Did you mean `Number(false)` ?

Comment: It's very unkind of you to limit other users to avoid suggesting better ways to perform your task, as there are many other better ways to do it.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, that's right. The double quotes in the question confuse. I'll edit it now. Thanks for that.

Comment: What kind of input field lets the user enter strings *and* booleans?

Comment: @Juhana a user could enter the word *false*. If I were using isNaN() function to test the data inputs, the result will be false because Number(false) converts to 0.

Comment: If the user enters the word "false" it is a string with the value "false". It won't be automatically converted into a boolean just because of that word.

Comment: Yes, you have right. I tried that I said you, in this [page](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm). I inspected the code, changed the maxlenght attribute in the inputs and when I added the *false* value, gives me the 000000 hex value (black color).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Number.isNaN()` function works differently than the global `isNaN()`. `Number.isNaN()` performs no type coercion.

Now, it's important to understand what the concept `NaN` means.  It does not simply mean, "something that is not a number".  It's about the floating point system, and specifically about values that don't mean anything. If you want to check whether some unknown value is a number, there are better ways of doing it. The `isNaN` functions are really about numerics.

A simple test:

```
function isNumberReally( n ) {
  return n === Number(n);
}
```

That uses the Number constructor to perform a conversion (if it can).  It then checks to see whether the result compares as equal to the original using the no-conversions `===` operator.  Only true primitive numbers pass that test; a string like "123" will not.

Comment: Also Number.IsNaN has limited support. Check this:- http://kangax.github.io/es5-compat-table/es6/#Number.isNaN

Comment: @MattBall yes I didn't like that either :)  THanks

Comment: Incredible answer! That's was looking for. Thanks @Pointy!

Comment: @leoMestizo your question/comments imply that you're taking user input from a text box. That value will always be a string, so if you pass it directly to this `isNumberReally` function, you'll always get back `false`. `"42"` is not `42`.

Comment: Yes, you have right too @MattBall. Perhaps, my comments or the question was a bit confuse, but this is I was looking for. I didn't know about the difference between isNaN() function and the Number.isNaN() method =). Thanks for the suggest.

Answer (score 1):

There really isn't a way to stop `isNan` from type conversion; Javascript does this automatically. However, you can try to create a a new `Number()` from the string of what you want to check, like this:

```
var a=false;
isNaN(Number(String(a)));//returns true;
```

Or you can check if something equals its number equivalent, like

```
return num===Number(num);
```

which basically does not convert types when checking equivalence.

In case you are open to other things, you could always use `typeof num==="number";`

Answer (score 1):

The `isNaN` function only works reliably on something that is already a number type. If you give it any other type, it will give results that are not consistent with what you might naturally expect.

Parse the string to a number, then you can use the `isNaN` function on it. The parsing can either result in a number or the value `NaN` (which is also of the type number), and `isNaN` can give you a consistent result from that. Example:

```
if (isNaN(parseFloat(textbox.value))) {
  alert('oops');
}
```

Note however, that the parsing will happily parse only part of the value. If someone enters a value like `123abc`, the `parseFloat` call will return the number `123`.

If you want the input to contain only a number and nothing else, you would need to verify it. For example using a regular expression that only accepts digits:

```
if (/^\d+$/.test(textbox.value)) {
  alert("fine");
}
```

Comment: Great answer, too! Thanks for your time Guffa!